# how to i get Total out of the method so that i can use it in increment...?

Tags: c#

```
namespace ConsoleApp2
{
    class Money
    {

        private int dollars;
        private int cents;

        public int Dollars
        {
            get { return dollars; }
            set
            {
                if (value > 0)
                    dollars = value;
            }
        }

        public int Cents
        {
            get { return cents; }
            set
            {
                if (value > 0)
                    cents = value;
            }
        }

        public Money(int D, int C)
        {
            Dollars = 5;
            Cents = 36;
        }

        public int ConvertToOne()
        {
            int Total;
            Total = Dollars + (Cents / 100);
            return Total;
        }
        public int IncrementMoney()
        {
            int IncAmmount;
            int NewBalance;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter decrement amount.");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter full dollar and cent amount: ");
            IncAmmount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            NewBalance = Total + IncAmmount;


        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int DecAmmount;

            Console.WriteLine("Welcome to the money exchange by Jason Rebelo");
            Console.WriteLine("Original Ammount" + "Dollars: " + dollars);
            Console.WriteLine("Cents:" + cents);
            DecAmmount = Console.Reaadline();

        }

    }
}
```

I feel like i'm missing something important to continue this code... I don't know how to get Total out of the `ConvertToOne` method to use in `IncrementMoney`.

I'm doing a a console app which should give out the following information

Original amount;
dollars : 5
cents: 36

Enter decrement amount.
Enter full dollar and cent ammount: 3.00 (inputed by user)

Original Amount: $5.36

Decrement Test:
Amount to Subtract: 3.00
New Dollar Amount: 2.00
New cent Amount: .36 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the Total out:

Int Total = ConvertToOne();